# rtorrent installation errors on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

I am getting a error while trying to install rtorrent on my ubuntu server.

```
./configure --with-xmlrpc-c
```

I am able to configure it successfully with above command but i get an error when i try to `make` also when i `make install`

See the image for error details: http://i50.tinypic.com/11t2wlh.jpg

Being a leaner i don't know what exactly the error is.

Comment: What version of xmlrpc-c is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xmlrpc-c version is probably out of date. See this ticket: http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/ticket/1593. Remove libxmlrpc-c3-dev libxmlrpc-c3 and get a copy of xmlrpc-c from SVN and use that. You may need to install svn.

```
$ cd ~/
$ svn checkout http://xmlrpc-c.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/xmlrpc-c/advanced xmlrpc-c
$ cd xmlrpc-c
$ ./configure --disable-cplusplus
$ gmake
$ gmake install
```